# How to search for a keyword in multiple csv files

Tags: python

How can I use `read_csv()` functions to search for a keyword ex: `EngineFuel" in multiple` .csv`if a folder`output``` and return the file name if a match is found. The keyword is always in the first row of a csv file.

Comment: You need to write code, which you do not appear to have even attempted.

Comment: `for file in fileList:` `with open(file) as f:` `w = csv.writer(f)` `for line in w:` `if string in line:` `return True`

Answer (score 0):

you can use regex to find for better performance

```
import pandas as pd
import re
def is_name_in_csv(word,csv_file):
  with open(csv_file,"r") as f:
    data = f.read()
  return bool(re.search(word, data))

list_file_csv = ['a.csv','b.csv','c.csv']
word = "EngineFuel"
for csv_file in list_file_csv:
  if is_name_in_csv(word,csv_file):
    print(f"find the {word} in {csv_file}")
```